# Como capturar somente uma parte específica de uma string?

Tags: regex

Usando expressão regular, gostaria de capturar somente o valor dentro de uma tag:

```
<txt_conarq_assunto></txt_conarq_assunto>
```

*Exemplo:*

**Entrada:**

```
<txt_conarq_assunto>A classificar</txt_conarq_assunto>
```

**Saída:**

A classificar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use o padrão  `<[tag]>(.*?)</[tag]>` para obter conteúdo entre elementos. Substitua [tag] pelo elemento real do qual você deseja extrair o conteúdo

```js
var texto = "<txt_conarq_assunto>A classificar</txt_conarq_assunto>";

texto.replace(/<txt_conarq_assunto>(.*?)<\/txt_conarq_assunto>/g, function(match, g1) { console.log(g1); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar essa expressão:

```
(?s)(?<=\<txt_conarq_assunto>)(.*?)(?=\<\/txt_conarq_assunto\>)
```

Exemplo funcional: https://regex101.com/r/JUaJDj/1

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `/<txt_conarq_assunto>(.+?)<\/txt_conarq_assunto>/`
Veja o exemplo abaixo, com `javascript`

```js
var texto = "<txt_conarq_assunto>A classificar</txt_conarq_assunto>";
var m = texto.match( /<txt_conarq_assunto>(.+?)<\/txt_conarq_assunto>/ );
console.log(m[1]);
```